# javascript generated links not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

there is a problem in ie8 related to links. html generated from javascript and display in the jquery ui dialog box but when I click on the link in it, it open link url in the same window (a tag has the targer=_blank set) and the url of link appended to the host url.

```
var clip_link = 'http://www.example.com/'+'c/'+id;
      var thumb = 'http://www.example.com/235/45'+'/thumb.jpg';
      $('#clip-share-popup .thumb').append(
        '<a href="'+clip_link+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+thumb+'" alt="clip thumb" /></a>'
      );
```

it is set after an ajax call

page url is 
`http://www.example.com/abcd.php#page/1/1`

after click on the link the url become 
`http://www.example.comhttp//www.example.com/c/1234#`

this doesn't happen in any other browser

Comment: can you give some sample code ?

Comment: It should be `target="_blank"`, or is that just a typo in your post? Also, could you post the code you have.

Comment: What's your question? Links work just fine in IE8 - it's your links that have the problem, but as you've not deemed it necessary to see your code, we're in the dark as to what's wrong.

Comment: Very poor question.. not enough details, not clear, way too general without seeing any code.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably not prefixing links with `http://`:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Would take you to `http://www.yourwebsite.com/whatever-page-you-are-on/www.google.com`